# How to insert a new script element on click to another element

Tags: javascript, onclick, widget

I am working on an application wherein a widget has a button that launches two others through a launching API. The API works perfectly, but I cannot get the calling function to work properly. When I just declared the API, using:

```
<script src="js/global.js"></script>
```

it worked fine, but launched as soon as the page was opened. I need it to launch on the button click instead.

I have the following code:

```
<a href='' id='mylink'>click me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');
myLink.onclick = function(){
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "js/global.js."; 
return false;
alert('ping');
}
```

I set up the alert to see where the process stops working. Everything before the "return" seems to run. I have tried this with both return true and return false, and it made no diference.

Comment: This is not the proper approach. Instead of this, you should alter the code in "global.js" so that the actions you want to take are encapsulated in a function to be called from the "click" event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to insert the script, try to append it to the head:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

So you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

 myLink.onclick = function(){
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "js/global.js."; 
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

</script>
```

Also in HTML try to use something else than an anchor as the anchor will try to send you somehwere else, the next code looks like an anchor but is a span:

```
<span style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline" id='mylink'>click me</span>
```

Comment: As far as the span, I decided to use a form with a button instead. I figured it would be more viable for eventing. 

I wound up just copying the function I was trying to run, and made it engage onclick.

Comment: Good, make sure to add onsubmit="return false" to your form :)

Answer (score 2):

`return` terminates execution of the function.

You did not add the `script` element to the document.

```
document.body.appendChild(script);
```